# Can't delete document on Lucene.Net

Tags: lucene.net

I am trying to delete a document but i am unable to delete it in any way. A specific thing that is related to my example that i am using RAMDirectory as directory and i am using Lucene.Net 3.0.3 version. My example is as below.

```
    public void DeleteIndex(IndexWriter writer,IndexSearcher searcher)
    {
        var boolQuery = new BooleanQuery();

        boolQuery.Add(new TermQuery(new Term("Id", "2")), Occur.MUST);
        boolQuery.Add(new TermQuery(new Term("Type", "Product")), Occur.MUST);

        writer.DeleteDocuments(boolQuery);
        writer.Optimize(true);
        //writer.Flush(true, true, true);//even this line doesn't help
        writer.Commit();

        var result = searcher.Search(boolQuery,1); // I can access deleted doc in search results
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

After writer.Commit(); you need to reopen you searcher.

```
IndexReader newReader = YOURIndexReader.Reopen(true);
searcher= new IndexSearcher(newReader );
...
```

The code example here are only examples, not a working code(!), i'm sure you can continue from here...

Comment: it doesn't change something.

Comment: Can you post more complete code ( how and when you create your Searcher, IndexReader and etc...)?